# External application is not accessible over reverse proxy

Tags: sql-server, iis, reverse-proxy

I am trying to access an application of our network from outside that was configured on Oracle database. Since I have had switched to SQL Server database, I cannot reach this application anymore from outside.

I have reverse-proxy-server with following IP:192.168.1.100 and the server IP:192.168.2.200. On the server is running the IIS Webserver with some applications and SQL Server. So far inside of the network, everything is working properly.

This is my reverse proxy configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
     ServerName application.gov.com 
     DocumentRoot /www/false 
     AddDefaultCharset off 
     SSLEngine on 
     Include  /etc/httpd/conf.d/star_application.gov.com.include 
     SSLProxyEngine On 
     SSLProxyVerify none 
     TimeOut 300 
     RewriteEngine on 
     RewriteRule ^/$ /Web/Application [L,R=301] 
     ProxyPass                /  https://servername.domaine.gov.com/ 
     ProxyPassReverse         /  https://servername.domaine.gov.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is the `web.config` from application one:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Frame-Options"></remove>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin"></add>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value=" https://servername.domaine.gov.com" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

and this is the `web.config` from application two:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <remove name="X-Frame-Options"></remove>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin"></add>
      <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://servername.domaine.gov.com" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

The reverse-proxy-server is located on its own VLAN and is not located on DMZ. Browser under F12 it says: Failed to load resource:net::err_connection_timed_out and the sand watch runs forever.

Thank you so much in advance for any help, in case this information is not sufficient for suggestions I will try to give more details.

Comment: You cannot reach the application, or the application cannot talk to the database?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: How does this relate to SQL Server? SQL Server uses TDS protocol on the default port of tcp/1433 and this all seems to be HTTPS configuration.

Comment: Set your reverse proxy to return detailed error so that you can know where the issue happened. You need to figure out if it is reverse proxy server or application server caused timeout issue.